# Duda cardinalidad 1:N o N:M

Tags: base-de-datos

Tengo una duda sobre que cardinalidad sería la siguiente frase: *"Un coche puede ser que se encuentre en un estado determinado. Los estados en los que se encuentra un coche se identifica por un id_estado. Además tendremos el nombre del estado. **Cabe destacar que un coche puede tener un estado (nuevo, averiado, etc...) en fechas diferentes y un estado puede repetirse en diferentes coches**"*

Dudo entre si es 1:N porque 1 coche tiene 1 estado y 1 estado lo tienen N coches. O si es N:M porque el coche tiene 1 estado pero en diferentes fechas, con lo que podría ser N estados.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con estado?, ¿uan ubicación física o las condiciones del coche?

Comment: ¿Dónde va la fecha?

Comment: @BetaM estado físico. Nuevo, averiado, etc.

Comment: @Antonio eso debería considero quedar claro en la pregunta

Comment: ¿Quieres registrar solo el estado actual o también el histórico?

Comment: @SJuan76 solo el actual

Comment: Si solo interesa registrar 1 estado para cada vehiculo y no importa un histórico, creería yo que con una relación 1:1 alcanza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Es N:M.

Supón que tienes los coches `A, B, C`. y que solo tienes dos estados `Nuevo, Disponible, Obsoleto`, es perfectamente valido tener combinaciones del estilo:

[image: ejemplo]

Podemos ver que un carro puede estar relacionado con distintos **estados** y un estado puede estar relacionado con **distintos** carros. Es decir es una relación de *todos contra todos*.

#### Tip

Puedes garantizar la unicidad gracias a la fecha, en mi caso solo puse un año pero aplica para más especificas al hacer la normalización puedes tener una llave primaría compuesta de `(id_coche, id_estado, fecha)`.

---

Podríamos ver un ejemplo de 1:N como si los carros se vendieran en regiones como `MX, EU, IND`, y en cada país solo puedes un grupo de carros que no puede repetirse en otro grupo.

Comment: Sería N:M aunque fuesen estados físicos? Es decir, un coche puede estar nuevo, pero en dos meses puede estar averiado. O eso serían restricciones CHECK del atributo id_estado?

Comment: @BetaM así es, olvide decir que son estados físicos que referencian al coche, ya está editada la pregunta

Comment: Creo que te confundes. A-E1, B-E1 y C-E1 sigue siendo una 1:N, porque la primera entidad solo puede tener un estado en un momento dado.

Comment: A-E1, A-E2, B-E1, C-E2 también podrían ser casos validos (con E1, E2 siendo *disponible*, *no disponible* respectivamente por ejemplo).

En realidad N:M contempla los casos que se presentan en 1:N, pero para el problema de @Antonio es necesario llevar la cardinalidad N:M